# Missing links in usage statements

Tags: documentation, finite-element-method

The integration of the documentation center does not seem to be complete on my machine. I often access the documentation center via the usage statement links.

```
?Sin
```

> Sin[z] gives the sine of z.  >>

Lately I have been exploring the FEM functions, but the usage statements do not have links even though the documentation can be accessed through the documentation center. For example,

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
?ToNumericalRegion
```

> NDSolve`FEM`ToNumericalRegion
>
> Attributes[ToNumericalRegion]={Protected,ReadProtected}
>
> Options[ToNumericalRegion]={MessageHead->Automatic}

Is there an update I can install or a file I can edit to add the links to the usage statements?

Comment: there were others like this. Someone forgot to add a link to the help page. btw, you should also mention that one needs to do "<<NDSolve`FEM`" before to even see anything about this command.

Comment: Just double-click `ToNumericalRegion` in either `?ToNumericalRegion` or any of its occurrences in the definition shown, then press `F1` and the help page will open.

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon, highlighting the keyword and pressing  `fn`+`F1` is definitely more convenient than what I have been doing. Still the question remains about updating the usage statements.

Comment: @TimothyWofford Even highlighting/double-click isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

In version 12.0 you get an information summary box that has a link to the documentation and some other information:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
?ToNumericalRegion
```

[image]